# Difference between "d'autant que", "d'autant plus que", and "d'autant moins que"

Tags: sens, expressions

> Je ne connais aucun autre homme aussi têtu. **D'autant (plus/moins) qu**'il n'était pas question de n'importe qui, mais de sa propre sœur.

Firstly, in the sentence above, which of these three expressions is really fit for use -- and why? When the preceding sentence has a negative construction such as "ne... aucun", is it necessary to use "d'autant **moins** que"?

Secondly, I’m not fully sure how these expressions differ in meaning from simply using "parce que".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parce que => Causality
D'autant plus => Causality + intensity. You add one more information about the importance.
D'autant moins => The intensity is negative : The more the weather is beautifull, the less you work => Less work will be used in french with negative intensity, D'autant moins : « Il va travailler peu, d'autant moins qu'il fait beau. »
D'autant plus => Same idea but positive : The more the weather is bad, the more you work => « Il va travailler beaucoup, d'autant plus qu'il fait mauvais temps. »

Comment: In my example sentence, would you use "d'autant plus que" or "d'autant moins que"? Merci.

Answer (score 1):

I found these usage notes in Larousse helpful:

**D'autant que, d'autant plus que** = vu que. Ces deux locutions sont correctes.

> << Rien ne me pressait ; d'autant que le service militaire me serait sans doute épargné >> (F. Mauriac)
>
> << La chaleur était suffocante, d'autant plus qu'on ne se sentait pas [...] l'espace et le vent de la mer >> (A. Daudet)

According to this, either 'd'autant que' or 'd'autant plus que' would be equally fit for use in the sentence above.